# How to export multivariate forecast results from R to excel

Tags: r, excel, export, forecasting

I'm terribly new with R, so I apologize if there's a way to do this using a slight variation of an existing code/package.

I've created yearly forecasts of a variable (student enrollment) for 129 countries using the predict command, and then i have them binded. I've done this because I'm forecasting using a multivariate regression.

*Here's what I'm doing (if this helps)*

```
`fm1=lm(log(y+1)~Var.Ind)
XNew=data.frame(Var.Ind)
(rse<-summary(fit)$sigma(fm1)* df.residual(fm1))/2
rse<-summary(fm1)$sigma
yhat1=exp(predict(fm1,XNew)+rse*rse/2)-1



 pos2014=which(Var.Ind[,1]==c(2014))
   Var.Ind.2015=model.matrix(~as.matrix(Imp.Data4[pos2014,-2])-1)
   head(Var.Ind.2015)
   Var.Ind.2015=data.frame(Var.Ind.2015)




Var.Ind.2015.Ord=as.data.frame(Var.Ind.2015[order(Var.Ind.2015[,3],Var.Ind.2015[,1]), ])
head(Var.Ind.2015.Ord)


X.New.New=data.frame(cbind(model.matrix(~as.matrix(Var.Ind.2015.Ord))))   
head(X.New.New)
ColNames.N=ColNames[-2]
colnames(X.New.New)=c("Int",ColNames.N,"Lag1","Lag2")
head(X.New.New)

Beta.Coef=matrix(as.numeric(fm1$coefficients),ncol=1)
Beta.Coef


Pred2015=as.data.frame(cbind(X.New.New[,3],exp(as.matrix(X.New.New)%*%Beta.Coef+rse*rse/2)-1))
dim(Pred2015)
colnames(Pred2015)=c("country","Yhat")
```

*And so on for subsequent years until 2030)

```
cbind(Pred2015, Pred2016, Pred2017, Pred2018, Pred2019)`
```

I need to figure out if there is a way to make sense of these results:

a) how to export the forecast results to excel
b) alternatively, if I could put these results into a table using R.

Also, these results do not appear in the Global Environment, only in the results section of the program, which is why I am not asking how to export data, but rather these specific results.

As previously mentioned, my coding knowledge is limited to my 1 week experience with R (I usually work with STATA).

Any help would  be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See `write.xlsx` and `addDataFrame` in the `xlsx` package.

Comment: The `xlsx` and `XLConnect` packages work. Alternately, you can just save it as a CSV which Excel can import with `write.csv`.

Comment: I'm guessing your main concern is formatting predictions before you export results rather than the actual export command. Can you post some data to provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks Alistair, in the end it turned out to be something pretty silly. I forgot to close the bundle. Problem solved.