# most efficient way to export contingency table from R to excel

Tags: r, excel, export

I am creating some contingency tables/crosstabs in R that I want to move to Excel for use in a Word document. I've found discussions on how to write to excel in a few questions- [How to export multivariate forecast results from R to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844276/how-to-export-multivariate-forecast-results-from-r-to-excel)
[Export data from R to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414605/export-data-from-r-to-excel). But contingency tables' formats (either using base R or packages like descr or gmodels) don't seem to translate well to Excel.

I've come up with my own solution, which produces what I want, but I wonder if there's a more efficient way, e.g. a package I'm overlooking.

```
library(xlsx)
test.data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample.int(2,size = 10*2, TRUE), nrow = 10, ncol = 2))
out1 <- table(test.data$V1, test.data$V2)
out.p <- prop.table(out1,2)
out.d <- as.data.frame.matrix(out1)
out.pd <- round(as.data.frame.matrix(out.p),2)
colnames(out.d) <- c("No", "Yes")
colnames(out.pd) <- c("No", "Yes")
out.d1 <- paste(out.d$No, " (",out.pd$No,")",sep="")
out.d2 <- paste(out.d$Yes," (",out.pd$Yes,")", sep="")
out2 <- cbind(out.d1,out.d2)
toadd.r <- c("No","Yes")
out2 <- cbind(toadd.r,out2)
sig <- unlist(summary(table(test.data$V1,test.data$V2)))
sig <- rep(round(sig[6],2),nrow(out2))
out2 <- cbind(out2, sig)
colnames(out2) <- c("Outcome","No","Yes","sig")
write.xlsx(out2, file ="Output.xlsx", sheetName = "Test1")
```

Comment: Questions asking  for "most efficient way to do X" are generally to broad for SO. This question is likely to be closed as such unless you provide a more more specific definition of what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am creating some contingency tables/crosstabs in R that I want to
>   move to Excel for use in a Word document.

if your final intention is to export to MS Word you should consider making use of the [`ReporteRs`](http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/index.html) package.

## Example

On example of your data you could use the code below to directly create a table in MS Word.

```
library(ReporteRs)
mydoc <- docx()
mydoc <- addFlexTable(mydoc, flextable = FlexTable(out2))
writeDoc(mydoc, file = "example.docx")
```

### Results

You will get a nice table in MS Word.
[image: exported table]

---

## Side point

The [FlexTable](https://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/FlexTable.html) object gives you a lot of options to adjust formatting and presentation.

[image: sample flex table with options]
***Source:*** [ReporteRs examples](https://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/FlexTable.html).

Comment: Perhaps mention that this can also be accomplished using `library(pander)` on an Rmarkdown file? Using `pander(out2)` in an R chunk can be used to export directly to a Word document as well.

Comment: @Twitch_City Integration with MS Office, can be achieved in a number of ways. RMarkdown is very good, I've suggested a solution using ReporteRs as, in my view, reflects OP's desire to 1) export to MS Word, 2) have some control over format, etc. Nothing wrong with using RMarkdown or any other solution.

Comment: this is helpful, thanks. I will look into Rmarkdown and reporteRs.

Answer (score 2):

I've been unable to find a package that outputs richly formatted contingency  tables to Excel from R, and have therefore been working on a package that does that:

The Github repo is [here](https://github.com/moj-analytical-services/xltabr) and docs [here](https://moj-analytical-services.github.io/xltabr/).

And you can install it using:
`devtools::install_github("moj-analytical-services/xltabr")`

In your use case, you'd need to run the following code:

```
df  <- data.frame(out2)
wb <- xltabr::auto_df_to_wb(df, left_header_colnames = "Outcome")
openxlsx::openXL(wb)
```

Which would produce the following output in Excel:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about simply

```
write.csv(out2, "myContingencyTable.csv")
```