# pivot wider - create two levels of headers for better readability

Tags: r, dplyr

There are six regression models. I used pivot wider but it is difficult to read.
Can I use two level of headers -

- first level - regression model
- second level - estimate, tstat

```
library(dplyr)

regression <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3), rep("D", 3), rep("E", 3), rep("F", 3))
attribute <- rep(c("b0", "b1", "b2"), 6)
estimate <- round(runif(n = 18, min = 0, max = 10), 2)
tstat <- round(runif(n = 18, min = 0, max = 10), 2)

# tibble
tbl <- tibble(regression, attribute, estimate, tstat)

# pivot wider
tbl <- tbl %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = regression,
              values_from = c("estimate", "tstat"))
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use this output? Putting header text into your numeric columns will turn those columns into characters, which will change how you're able to work with them. Or is it for output in e.g. an Rmarkdown document, in which case you'd want to use a package that's specific to formatting tables for display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `separate_header` from `ftExtra`

```
library(ftExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
tbl %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = regression,
                 values_from = c("estimate", "tstat")) %>% 
     rename_with(~ str_replace(., "(.*)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1"), -1) %>%
     as_flextable() %>%
     separate_header()
```

-output

[image]

---

Or may use `span_header`

```
library(flextable)
tbl %>%  
  pivot_wider(names_from = regression,
              values_from = c("estimate", "tstat")) %>%   
  rename_with(~ str_replace(., "(.*)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1"), -1) %>% 
  select(attribute, order(str_remove(names(.)[-1], "_.*")) + 1) %>% 
  as_flextable() %>% 
  span_header()  %>% 
  align(align = "center", part = "all")
```

-output
[image]

---

If we need to make some column **bold**,

```
tbl %>%  
    pivot_wider(names_from = regression,
                values_from = c("estimate", "tstat")) %>%   
    rename_with(~ str_replace(., "(.*)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1"), -1) %>% 
    mutate(across(ends_with('tstat'),  ~sprintf('**%.2f**', .))) %>% 
    select(attribute, order(str_remove(names(.)[-1], "_.*")) + 1) %>% 
    as_flextable() %>% 
    span_header()  %>% 
    align(align = "center", part = "all") %>% 
    colformat_md()
```

-output

[image]

Comment: thanks. is it possiblr group regression models together (for ex - As, Bs, ...)

Comment: Thnaks, thats almost correct, the upper level headers are not accurate (A should span from estimate to tstat)

Comment: Thnaks, thats almost correct, the upper level headers are not accurate (A should span from estimate to tstat and should be in the middle)

Comment: @SiD that just needs an `align` from `flextable`.  Updated

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: @akrun: How did you handle duplicate column names. I tried 1 hour to solve this with flextable?

Comment: @TarJae there was no duplicate column names per se. if you check the output until the `select` step.  The `span_header` or `separate_header` does the split at the `_` to split the column names.  The columns are ordered so that all columns that start with 'A' are adjacent, followed by 'B' columns, etc and then we apply the span_header.  It is just like `head(iris) %>%
    as_flextable() %>%
     span_header() %>% align(align = "center", part = "all")`

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks master!

Comment: @akrun can i write the final results in csv file. It seems that it is image

Comment: @SiD That is why i said in the comments earlier that data.frame/tibble doesn't allow multiple headers. You can save as an image. if the output object is `out` `save_as_image(out, path = "out.png", webshot = "webshot2")`

Comment: okay, got it thanks

Comment: @SiD You may also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866714/most-efficient-way-to-export-contingency-table-from-r-to-excel) for alternative ways

Comment: @akrun just wondering, is it possible in R to bold estimate values in table , based on tstat value so it is more readable

Comment: @SiD try the update

Comment: @SiD if you have more questions, please consider to post as a new question. thanks