# conditionally bold values in flextable

Tags: r, dplyr, flextable

Is it possible to bold/color estimate values based on tstat.

For ex - bold estimate values if tstat is more than 1.96

This is in continuation of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69780809/pivot-wider-create-two-levels-of-headers-for-better-readability) and I have to use flextable.

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)


attribute <- c("b0", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5")
estimate <- round(runif(n = 6, min = 0, max = 5), 2)
tstat <- round(runif(n = 6, min = 0, max = 5), 2)

# tibble
tbl <- tibble(attribute, estimate, tstat) %>%
  as_flextable()
```

Comment: A, B, C, D, E, F :-)

Comment: @akrun sorry I have removed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution using flextable *row selector*:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)

set.seed(4123)

attribute <- c("b0", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5")
estimate <- round(runif(n = 6, min = 0, max = 5), 2)
tstat <- round(runif(n = 6, min = 0, max = 5), 2)

tbl <- tibble(attribute, estimate, tstat)

tbl %>%   
  flextable() %>% 
  bold(~ tstat > 1.96,2)
```

[image]

Comment: tbl %>%   
  flextable() %>% 
  __flextable__::bold(~ tstat > 1.96,2) - that was essential in my case to specify exactly which library it is from as crayon and gt libraries were also active within the same R session and all of then had function bold()

Comment: @AnnaZ if only I saw this earlier, it would have saved me hours of debugging just now!

Answer (score 2):

We could use either `ifelse` or `case_when` to add the `**<value>**` for `bold`ing

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)
tbl <- tibble( attribute, estimate, tstat) %>%
       mutate(estimate = case_when(tstat > 1.96 
            ~sprintf('**%0.2f**', estimate), 
          TRUE  ~sprintf('%0.2f', estimate))) %>%
  as_flextable() %>%
  colformat_md()
tbl
```

-output

[image]

Comment: okay thanks a lot, although I have to bold the estimate value based on tstat

Comment: @SiD that is easier, just change it to `estimate` based on the comparision on tstat'.  updated

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)

set.seed(4123)

attribute <- c("b0", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5")
estimate <- round(runif(n = 6, min = 0, max = 5), 2)
tstat <- round(runif(n = 6, min = 0, max = 5), 2)

tbl <- tibble(attribute, estimate, tstat)
  
tbl %>%   
  flextable() %>% 
  bold(tbl$tstat > 1.96,2)
```

[image]